# Sequelize Grant privileges to user for all tables, executed correctly, but not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize-typescript

When i am creating a spefic tenant database , i create the database with the sequelize connection established , which manipulates the Master database.

```
masterDBsequelize.query(`CREATE DATABASE ${createdTenant.databaseName}`);
```

And after the creation of the database using the `createdTenant` record *(which is a record saved in the master database)* I connect to that specific databaase with:

```
const dbOptions = {
    host: DATABASE_HOST,
    port: DATABASE_PORT,
    database: createdTenant.databaseName,
    username: MASTER_DATABASE_USER_NAME,
    password: MASTER_DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    dialect: 'postgres'
  };

  const tenantSequelize: Sequelize = new Sequelize(dbOptions);
```

It is important to mention that i use `sequelize-typescript` library.

After that i create user with the master database connection:

```
const username = `user_123}`;
const password = `userPassword_123`;
const createUserQuery = `CREATE USER ${username} WITH PASSWORD '${password}'`;

await masterDbSequelize.sequelize.query(createUserQuery, { transaction });
```

After that grant privilages with tenant specific database connection:

```
const grantPrivilegesQuery = `
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA public TO ${username}; 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE "Device" TO ${username};`;

await tenantSequelize.query(grantPrivilegesQuery, { transaction });
```

In the console i receive the whole string which confirms the creation of the database the granting of the privalages. When that happens i diconnect from the database.

And when i execute http request to connect to the Tenant database with the needed credentials it established the conneciton succesfullt using the `authenticate()` method of Sequelize the promise returned is successfull . And when i try to create a record in Device table i receive an error:

```
Error on executing createDevice SequelizeDatabaseError: permission denied for table Device
```

When i check in PGAdmin  the created users and their privileges on the created user `user_123}` it shows that it has `canLogin`  & `inherit rights from parent roles` .